# Proving a limit using the Mean Value Theorem

Tags: limits

I have been asked to show:

$\lim_{n\to \infty}\sqrt{n+1} - \sqrt{n}=0$

I am supposed to do this by applying the Mean Value Theorem to the function $f(x) = \sqrt{x}$. I was thinking of applying the MVT on the interval $[n, n+1]$ but do not see where to go from there...Any ideas? Thanks all!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By the mean value theorem, there exists a $c \in (n, n + 1)$ such that

$$\frac{\sqrt{n + 1} - \sqrt{n}}{(n + 1) - n} = f'(c)$$

or alternatively,

$$\sqrt{n + 1} - \sqrt{n} = \frac{1}{2 \sqrt{c}}$$

Now $c \ge n$, so....

Comment: Would the downvoter mind explaining? If there's an error or omission, I'd be happy to fix it.

Comment: It wasn't me (Me was +1), but if you want to be precise, $\sqrt{c} \geq \sqrt{n}$ is what you need, and you already showed it in the body of the question, but didn't mention it. And that $\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt{n} \geq 0$. Is all this not necessary? (I'm really asking you, not criticizing).

Comment: Or just ignore...